# How can I run my AndroidTestCases in debug mode in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing

Running an AndroidTestCase normally in Android Studio works fine.

When I try to run the test in debug mode, however, I am stuck at "Instantiating tests...":

[image]

How can I run my AndroidTestCases in debug mode in Android Studio?

Comment: Could you explain how you expect that to work? Your tests will be trying to run the code while it is running in a suspended debug state at the same time.

Comment: I want to hit breakpoints in my test cases so I can figure out why they are failing

Answer (score 0):

What a PitA.

Run > Edit Configurations > "TestName" > Miscellaneous

Then uncheck the displayed installation options. Not sure why this works but it does